# Installing pear package debian squees

Tags: debian, packages, pear

I try to install the php pear package on my debian server but I got the follow error ouput.

```
:~# sudo apt-get install php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  php5-suhosin
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  php5-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-pear
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 366 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,407 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://packages.dotdeb.org/ squeeze/all php-pear all 5.3.21-1~dotdeb.0
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/binary-all/php-pear_5.3.21-1~dotdeb.0_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*apt-get update

apt-get install php-pear*

this should do the trick